# print variable in a way to evaluate/use it afterwards

Tags: r

I always have a little problem, providing a little minimal working example to you at stack overflow.

Is there a way to print, for example a data frame, so I can copy and paste it into the R console again and create the same kind of variable?

so basically something like this:

```
awesomePrint(df)
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  y = c(2, 3, 4, 5)
)
```

Comment: Just try `dput(df)`. The function you are looking for is `dput`.

Comment: Thank you @nicola, could you post an answer so I can mark it as solved.

Comment: @drmariod You should definitely read the FAQ [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) where, among other very useful things, `dput` is described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `dput` function, that prints the command you need to recreate an object.

```
 df<-data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4),y = c(2, 3, 4, 5))
 dput(df)
```

You can also use `dump` to write that line on a file or on the standard output:

```
 dump("df","")
```